# WCF Self Hosted REST + SSL + custom user password authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, ssl, wcf-security

I have WCF 4.0 project and I try to add more secure layers to my web service.

My web service is self hosted and support soap (BasicHttpBinding) and rest (WebHttpBinding) together. I don't have any problem in SSL support. Both binding is working good under SSL. But when I try to add custom user password authentication support to my service, BasicHttpBinding has TransportWithMessageCredential SecurityMode but WebHttpBinding has only Transport SecurityMode. This means BasicHttpBinding support SSL+username but WebHttpBinding support only SSL or only username support (TransportCredentialOnly)

Have any idea how can I implement **custom user password authentication whit SSL on WebHttpBinding**  (REST) ?

Thank you

Sefer

Comment: Ok, I solve my problem myself, if we set ClientCredentialType to Basic we are going to have ssl + username/password protection

bBind.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
bBind.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;